# Python daemon threads and the "with" statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, daemon, python-multithreading, with-statement

If I have the following code in a daemon thread and the main thread does not do invoke a join on the daemon. Will the file close safely since it is used inside "with" once the main thread exits or no? Anyway to make it safe? Thanks :D

```
while True:
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        cfg = f.readlines()
time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> Note: Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.

This suggests, but does not outright state, that daemon threads are terminated without a chance for `__exit__` methods and `finally` blocks to run. We can run an experiment to verify that this is the case:

```
import contextlib
import threading
import time

@contextlib.contextmanager
def cm():
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print 'in __exit__'

def f():
    with cm():
        print 'in with block'
        event.set()
        time.sleep(10)

event = threading.Event()

t = threading.Thread(target=f)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

event.wait()
```

where we start a daemon thread and leave it sleeping in a `with` block when the main thread exits. When we [run the experiment](http://ideone.com/Lc5KBj), we get an output of

```
in with block
```

but no `in __exit__`, so the `__exit__` method never gets a chance to run.

---

If you want cleanup, don't use a daemon thread. Use a regular thread, and tell it to shut down at the end of the main thread through the regular inter-thread communication channels.

Comment: Thank you for that quick answer. So essentially according to my question the file is left open in read mode? A follow up question - does that render the file unusable?

Comment: @SamThomas: The operating system should automatically close the process's open file handles at the OS level when the process exits, but that won't necessarily do things like flush output buffers for files open in write mode.

Comment: So in such a case, as above, daemon usage is safe right ?

Comment: @Sam: It's safe if all the thread is doing is _reading_ a file (so there's no need to flush its output buffers before it's closed).

Comment: user2357112: What kind of regular inter-thread communication channel would you recommend / think would be best to handle such a shutdown signals? Could you add an example of using it to your answer?